# How can i initializing my View without using some View{} in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple View called TextView, I could make this View working without explicitly using **some View**  like this code:

```
struct TextView: View {

    var body = Text("Hello, world!")
 
}
```

now I like to control the String also like this code:

```
struct TextView: View {

    let stringOfText: String
    
    init(stringOfText: String) {
        self.stringOfText = stringOfText
    }

    var body = Text(stringOfText)
 
}
```

with second code I get this Error:

[image]

How could I possibly solve this issue without using Binding or State wrappers?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I don't think it is a good way - what you're trying to do is kind of against common SwiftUI practices and may be hard to read for others. I suggest you use this for learning purposes only. The error occurs because `body` is no longer a computed property, thus, you can't initialise it with other properties outside init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have doubts all this is good SwiftUI code style, but following your first part you can use

```
struct TextView: View {
    var body: Text

    init(stringOfText: String) {
        body = Text(stringOfText)
    }
}
```